# Crystal: clear values in "Current Parameter Values"

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

I have a custom SQL with parameters.  There are no defaults in either the SQL Editor, or in the parameter editor.  Also, "Save Data with Report" is unchecked.  The strange thing is, when I go to Report -> "Show Current Parameter Values" I see read-only values for both parameters.

Do you know how to remove those?  The goal is to provide NEW values on first open without having to run the query on the invalid default values.

CR version 11

Answer (score 1):

I ended up changing and re-saving with an updated SQL statement and those pesky default values went away.  It is easier to prompt for new parameters now.

Answer (score 0):

Remove or change the parameters' values in the `Parameter Fields` node in the `Field Explorer`.

Comment: Thank you.  One of the parameters did not have a value but still showed a default.